# In the triangle, prove that the sine of any angle is smaller than the sum of the sines of the other angles.

Tags: trigonometry

In the triangle, prove that the sine of any angle is smaller than the sum of the sines of the other angles.

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Two_Sides_of_Triangle_Greater_than_Third_Side

Comment: This question can be improved by adding more detail. What is your background? What level of a proof do you need? Where did you see this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a,b,c $ be the angles of your triangle.

then

$$\sin (a)=\sin (\pi-(b+c)) $$

$$=\sin (b+c) $$

$$=\sin (b)\cos (c)+\sin (c)\cos (b) $$

$$\leq \sin (b)+\sin (c) $$

if

$$0\leq\cos (c)\leq 1\;,\; 0\leq \cos (b)\leq 1.$$

Comment: +1, But you don't need $\cos c,\cos b$ positive, since $\sin a,\sin b,\sin c$ are positive...

Answer (score 1):

C'+B' are bigger than A' ...
So : 
K sin c + K sin B are bigger than K sin A ...
 Dividing  both sides over K ..
Sin c + sin b is bigger than sin A

Comment: What is $K$? What are $C',B'$ relative to the angles?

Comment: C' is a side of the triangle , and K i got it from the sines law of the side over the sine of the opposite angle when I suppose it equals to K

Comment: A'/sin A = B'/sinB = C'/sinC =K ( supposition)